# Hibernate lazy loading, nullify lazy object

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, struts2

I do some query with Hibernate and I use the beans automatically generated by Hibernate. In these beans there are some set of objects with the annotation lazy loading (fetch=FetchType.LAZY), if I debug the code, all object are loaded correctly except these, where I see: com.sun.jdi.InvocationException

I don't need to load this set with the Lazy annotation, I would like to have it null (because after I need to create an xml, and I don't want it in the xml. (I wouldn't like to use @XmlTransient, I want it null if it is possible)).

Is it possible to have the Lazy variables to null, without modify the annotations? (For example setting some directives through code before of executing the query).

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: They will not load if you won't debug em.

Comment: But when I generate the xml from the object, I receive an error. I would like to have them null, so I don't have them in my xml.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you add the @XmlTransient annotation to the getter method rather than the field.

JAXB annotations use the property accessors rather than the fields by default.

Comment: I already wrote: (I wouldn't like to use @XmlTransient, I want it null if it is possible)).